# AngularJS and JQuery DataTables server-side processing: aDataSort undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatable

I created a directive for JQuery DataTables in AngularJS and it works with each data source types, except server-side processing. With the latter I get an error saying: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined`.

I have the following code in the directive's `link` function:

```
var buildTableFromServer = function() {
    var table = $(el).find('table');

    if (! $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable(table)) {
        table.DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": scope.dataSource
        });
    }
}
```

The error stack I get points to the line where I call `.DataTables()` (after some lines in DataTables JS file).

I checked and `table` is found, `scope.dataSource` is set (it's a URL string, the one used in the [example](http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)). Moving the DT code outside of the if block does nothing either.

What could be the problem? If needed, I can provide more code, but I don't think any more would help.

Comment: Were you able to resolved this issue? Even I am getting same error.

Comment: No, I made a workaround, but sadly I don't remember anymore. :/